# Design multi-column display for ListView in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-gridview

I am trying to implement multi-column in ListView. Currently I have used a GridView for each row to give Column look. However I can think of one more approach of making the ListView row contain all the column Layout of Gridview and while binding iterate over the layout and assign data.

Approach #1: ListViewRow-> contains GridView
             GridViewRow-> Layout for each column

Approach #2: ListViewRow contains say 12 LinearLayouts each having its own display (display wise all LinearLayouts are same). [Similar to this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/)

Which of these approaches will be good in performance terms?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at relative layout, maybe you can use it in your listviewrow